# Finding a string using grep?

Tags: php, html, string, grep

I need to use grep to find a specific string in a log file.
I would use other methods, however I have to use this for an assignment.
Does anyone have anyway of doing this?

Comment: Have you done any research yet? (for example: google)

Comment: I'd write some code to do it for me, It would be a nightmare to do it manually.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Finding a string using grep or php, or both? Please rephrase your question. `I would user other methods`, you use, or user use other methods? Please make your question more clear as it doesn't make sense. If you want to use grep, you just do: `grep string file.log`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the command line [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep), then you can execute shell commands using the [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function, it returns the output as a string:

```
$output = shell_exec('grep pattern file');
```